# language swith in jquery-mobile and phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

i am writing a app using jquery-mobile and phonegap and i try to make it multiple language.
RIght now, i can make it works except two external pages. and it works all the internal page, like .
but the two external pages is not working. 
my javascript is include in the index.html which contains all the internal pages.
how can i solve this problem.
any suggestions are great help. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to bind some code onto the "pageload" event and then detect the IDs of the external pages and run any necessary operations prior to showing the page.

If I'm not mistaken this should work:

```
$("[data-role=page]").live("pageload", function(event,data) {
    if (this.attr("id") == "externalPageId") {
        // perform necessary operations
    }         
});
```